# Basic Songkick API XML parse with loop

Tags: php, xml, api, parsing

i'm trying to parse the Songkick API into a list of an artist's upcoming show dates.  From what i've been able to find, the following should do that.  The problem is, it doesn't work.

The code returns nothing at all.

```
$artist_id = "id";
$api_key = "API key";

$request_url    =    urlencode("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/" . $artist_id . "/calendar.xml?apikey=" . $api_key);
$load_api           =    simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("Songkick API error.");

foreach ($load_api->event as $shows) {
        $venue      =   $shows->venue["displayName"];
        $city       =   $shows->location["city"];
        $skdate =   $shows->start["date"];
                            $date = date("M d", strtotime($skdate));
        $artists    =   $shows->event->performance->artist["displayName"];

        echo $shows;
        echo $city;
        echo $date;
        echo $artists;
```

The XML file looks like several instances of the following:

```
<event type="Concert" status="ok" displayName="Band with supporting acts" popularity="0.000495" uri="songkick address for this show" id="248">
        <metroArea displayName="SF Bay Area" uri="songkick address for this metro area" id="26330">
            <state displayName="CA"/>
            <country displayName="US"/>
        </metroArea>
    </venue>
    <start time="21:30:00" datetime="2013-05-31T21:30:00-0800" date="2013-05-31"/>
    <location lat="37.7650545" lng="-122.3963593" city="San Francisco, CA, US"/>
    <performance billingIndex="1" displayName="headliner" billing="headline" id="31239239">
        <artist displayName="Band Name" uri="uri for headling band" id="4114066"/>
    </performance>
    <performance billingIndex="2" displayName="Opener 1" billing="support" id="31239244">
        <artist displayName="Opener 1" uri="Opener 1 uri to songkick band page" id="4852118"/>
    </performance>
    <performance billingIndex="3" displayName="Opener 2" billing="support" id="31239249">
        <artist displayName="Opener 2" uri="Opener 2 uri to songkick band page" id="3527036"/>
    </performance>
</event>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated...i'm at a loss.

Thanks!

---

UPDATE: Figured it out!  Thanks!

```
<?php
    $artist_id  =   "*songkick artist id*";
    $api_key    =   "*api key*";
    $perm_link  =   "http://www.songkick.com/artists/$artist_id";

    $request_url    =   "http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/" . $artist_id . "/calendar.xml?apikey=" . $api_key;
    $xml            =   simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("Songkick API error.  Click <a href=\"" . $perm_link . "\" target=\"_blank\">Click here for show dates</a>."); // load file, or if error, print direct link to songkick page

    foreach ($xml->results->event as $event) {
        $skdate     =   $event->start["date"];
            $date   =   date("M d", strtotime($skdate));
        $venue      =   $event->venue["displayName"];
        $city       =   $event->location["city"];
        $artists    =   $event->xpath("./performance/artist/@displayName");

        echo $venue, $city, $date . ":<br />" . implode(', ',$artists) . "<br />";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Good job, +1 for sharing solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to debug your code:

1. your XML above is not valid --> http://www.xmlvalidation.com
2. make sure `$load_api` contains what you think it does by using `var_dump($load_api);`
3. make sure PHP's error reporting is at its best level, search SO for how to do that.
4. your XML has multiple `<artist>` nodes, so `$artists` has to be set differently.
5. you `echo $shows` which is echoing - nothing, because it has children, but no value.

   ```
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume **valid** XML in $x

   foreach ($xml->event as $shows) {
       $venue = $shows->venue["displayName"];
       $city  = $shows->location["city"];
       $date = date("M d", strtotime($shows->start["date"]));
       $artists = $shows->xpath("//artist/@displayName"); // returns array!

       echo "$city $date: " . implode(', ',$artists) . "<br />";
   }
   ```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/yrAjYI

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  i checked the actual XML file returned from the API with the XML validator, and no errors were found.  Also, the XML i posted was a snippet for just one show.

While i'm admittedly new to XML, i did notice that the songkick API seemed strange, because the tags themselves contain no values.  All the data is contained in the tag attributes, which (i think) is the reason i can't get the foreach() loop working.

Comment: `foreach ($xml as $show) {
 $venue = $show->event->venue["displayName"];
}
echo $venue;`

returns a venue name, but the following returns an 'Undefined Variable' error.

`foreach ($xml->event as $show) {
 $venue = $show->venue["displayName"];
}

echo $venue;`